# 100% width footer without wrapper

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it was possible to have a 100% width footer for a 980px content without any #wrappers or Divs in the code? I'm a fan of [camendesign's](http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres) ethos, but due to the method of having the body as a wrapper - the footer remains wrapped too.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you look at the source of camendesign, you can see he uses the `footer` element with `position: fixed`.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at his own code again - I've just noticed he doesn't use body! Instead he has article as well as footer nav as margin: 0 auto;. I may just remove the wrap on the body and have it on the article to free up the footer.

Comment: Realize that the HTML `body` is always present in the DOM, though. Whether you actually write `<body></body>` in your HTML or not, Web browsers will always make sure the DOM is correct. Again, if you look at camendesign's source, you will see he actually styles the `body` with CSS, even though the HTML is not there. I made a little [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acjbizar/esv3G/) that illustrates this effect.

Comment: I did wonder. Interesting. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the footer absolute position with width 100%

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ExY78/1/